# 'Vector Smart Object' issue on Creative Cloud

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

I updated to Creative Cloud 2015 from 2014 recently and I am having a series of weird issues working with smart objects.

First issue happens while pasting into PhotoShop (PS):

Let's say I created a vector object in Adobe Illustrator (AI), copied it and pasted into PS.

I don't get any paste options; the application directly pastes it as an embedded vector smart object.

To be more clear, I saw people talking about a dialog option to uncheck 'add to my library' to make it an embedded object. This is not my issue. No matter what, I don't get any dialogue to choose how to paste into PS. It is always an embedded vector smart object; it does not matter if I uncheck the option to always paste as smart object from preferences panel.

---

The second issue occurs if I want to edit contents of a vector smart object:

Does not matter if I created this vector smart object recently or if it was working properly before the application update; when I double-click on the icon on the vector smart object layer, it launches AI as it is supposed to do. Then in AI, I get a 'Text Import Options' dialog box where I need to choose encoding, and then I get export SVG plugin data pasted as text instead of the vector I am trying to edit.

I tried resetting my presets and options. All the applications are up to date. I don't have any plugins installed.

I have not found anyone on the web with same issue.

Also, now, if I select a group of objects containing a text layer in AI, I can't paste that group to PS without converting the text to vector. If I try to, PS gives out an error saying PostScript data is empty.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am working on Mac OsX 10.11.3

Photoshop 2015.1.2 Release Illustrator 2015.2.1

I still have this issue and it is driving me crazy. 

When I try to double click on a vector object icon that I just created by copy/pasting from illustrator, AI tries to import as ascii text and I get the Postscript text instead of the vector data. 

Also If I try to export contents from PS, I again get a Postscript error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reformatting of OSx several times and installing applications, one by one, I figured out the issue: Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 conflicts with Notability. Completely uninstalling Notability and restarting the system fixes the issue.